# How to avoid line wrap in jenkins output console?

Tags: jenkins

How can I avoid Jenkins from wrapping long lines in the console output?

I want the lines to keep the original formatting, with spaces and line break, just avoid wrapping when looking at the console output in Chrome.

I use Chrome and Jenkins 2.107.2.

Comment: The *word-wrap* property seen in console is set in the main jenkins [style.css](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/war/src/main/webapp/css/style.css). There might be a way to override it with some plugin, have not looked into this. You can just change it for a test in `$JENKINS_HOME/war/css/style.css`, You will get a scroll bar for longer lines. However there seems to be another line-breaking property, it breaks the line after 427 characters even with scrollbar. Edit: May i ask what your use-case is? I would think its nice to have longer lines wrapped in the visible space.

Comment: I have an SQL checking job, that returns the query result in a large ascii table, which is totally unreadable when lines break, as visible columns disappear.